# Unexpected non-void return value in void function Swift

Tags: swift, function, networking, boolean

I started learning to work with swift today.

Unfortunately I got an error by trying to return a boolean by a function which checks if there is a connection to a network.

```
import SwiftUI
import Network

let monitor = NWPathMonitor()

func CheckNetworkConnection() -> Bool {
    monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
        if path.status == .satisfied {
            var connection = true
        } else {
            var connection = false
        }

        return connection //<--- Unexpected non-void return value in void function
    }
}
```

Thank you for everyone who can help!

Comment: This looks like an asynchronous call which is a strange choice to program something like that if it is your first day with swift. May I suggest you start reading [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) book to learn the basics and then maybe start with something simpler for your first project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Answer (score 1):

First your connection variable only valid in {}, second the pathUpdateHandler is inal public var pathUpdateHandler: ((NWPath) -> Void)? so you can't return a Bool. Maybe you can change to something like thing

```
 func CheckNetworkConnection(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            let connection = path.status == .satisfied ? true : false
            completion(connection)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! The errors are gone but I don't understand how to get the result of the return? ````if CheckNetworkConnection(completion: <#T##(Bool) -> Void#>) = true {}````?

Comment: you should read more about closure, you will find the answer

Comment: using like below:         CheckNetworkConnection { (connection) in
            if connection {
                ...
            }
        }